# how to formulate the series $1,2,4,8,16,3,5,9,17 ....$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose a number is given = $5$ then from the number how to formulate the series -

$1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 3, 5, 9, 17, 6, 10, 18, 12, 20, 24, 7, 13, 21, 11, 19,  ...$

actually I want a function of n and the given number m (5 in this case) such that f(1)=1, $f(2) = 2, f(3)=4 ... f(6)=3, f(7) = 5$ like this

Background of the problem : I faced a situation where I needed to find out all possible combination of $5$ digit binary number in a specific order like - $1,10,100,1000,10000,11,101,1001,10001 ....$ i.e. all possible combination of one 1 digit in the $5$ digit precedes all possible combination of two $1$ digit in $5$ digit combination (if possible in the order too) so on

Any solution? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, how is exactly $5$ related to your wonderful sequence? And what is exactly the rule of the sequence? Is it just an arbitrary denumeration of all positive integers?

Comment: This seems very closely related to the "combinatorial number system," see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

Comment: Ah, I see now, your sequence will have $31$ numbers (excluding $0$, as I see), and the first $n$ numbers are just the powers of $2$. (Now $n=5$.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson +1 Though the information is very useful, but does not quite solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed this formulation for the problem, for simplification i ranked the numbers in a decreasing fashion (within a set of numbers with a fixed number of digits set to one) as I didn't get how the local rank mechanism of the original post worked (it starts with a decreasing fashion then deviate from this logic), i reordered the items in a decreasing while being confident about the possibility of formulating other ordering strategies.

Notations:

- The $\sum$ over an empty set is 0
- ${n \choose k}$ is 0 for a negative value of k.
- $d_i(b)$ (or $d_i$ for simplification)  is the $i^{th}$ digit of b (it's also the coefficient of $2^{i-1}$ that can be easily formulated as a recursive function of b).
- c(b) is the the number of digits set to 1 in b (easily formulable as a recursive function of b).
- $S_m^i$ is the set of numbers given $c(b)=i$  and  $b<2^m$
- $r_l(b)$ is the (local) rank of b within its containing $S_m^i$ (The bigger a number is, smaller is its rank)
- $r_g(b)$ is the (global) rank of the number b.

Properties:

- $card(S_m^i)={m \choose i}$
- If ($c(b)=1$) then $r_g(b)=r_l(b)$
- $\forall$ b given $c(b)\geq2$ we can easily prove that:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   r_g(b) =& \sum_{1\leq i\leq c(b)-1} card(S_m^i) + r_l(b)\\
  \qquad =& \sum_{1\leq i\leq c(b)-1} {m \choose i} + r_l(b)\\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$
- $\forall \;b\; \in  S_m^i$:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   r_l(b) =& 1 \;+\; \sum_{1\leq j\leq m}{(1-d_{m-j})*{{m-j}\choose {i-(1+\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}})} }}*h_j^i(d)\\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$
  Where:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  h_j^i(d) =&\frac{i-(\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}})}{max(1\;,\;(i-\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}}))}\;
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$

The last formula  can be intuitively explained as follows: Let d $\in S_m^i$
If the $j^th$ digit (coefficient of $2^{j-1}$) is set to 0, the rank of d is for sure after all the numbers having the $j^{th}$ digit set to 1 and having the same digits configuration as d before this $j^th$ digit. There are ${{m-j} \choose  {i-(1+\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}})} }$ ones verifying this last assumption. Why ?

Let's take a closer look :

Assume d = $b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_{j+1} \color{red}{b_j }   b_{j-1} ... b_0 $

if $\color{red}{b_j } = 0$ then we know that the numbers having the same digit configuration as b before the $j^th$ bit (starting also with $b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_{j+1}$ ) but having $b'_j=1$ are greater than b. How many are they?

First, we know that those numbers still have ${m-j}$ digits at the right of $b'_j$. How many of those remaining digits can be set to one?

Answer : ${i-(1+\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}})}$ because those numbers have already $\sum_{1\leq k\leq j-1}{d_{m-k}}$ digits set to 1, to which we add one as  $p_j$ is also set to 1!

However, and here comes the aim of the function h, d should not be penalized by the 0 digits that comes at the right of its last 1 digit. For the simple reason that it is impossible to have other numbers that have digits set to one at this level (Remember that we're on sets of numbers with a fixed number of digits set to 1)

Therefore, we need to define a function that cancels the penalization for those zeros. As soon as j (the sum index) is at the level of those zeros the function takes 0, before that index the function takes 1.

An Example:

10000

01000

00100

00010

00001

11000

10100

10010

10001

01100

01010 -> The rank here is 11.

01001

...

$r_g(01010)={5 \choose 1} + r_l(01010)$

$r_l(01010)=1 + (1-0)*{4 \choose 1}*1 + (1-1)*{3 \choose 1}*1 + (1-0)*{2 \choose 0}*1 + (1-1)*{1 \choose 0}*1 + (1-0)*{0 \choose 0}*0$

$r_l(01010)= 1+ 4 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 6$

Then : $r_g(01010)= 5 + 6 = 11$